# Covariance of binary and continuous variable

Tags: variance, covariance, binary-data

Suppose $y$ is a continuous random variable and $d$ is a binary random variable that takes the value $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$.

How do I show that $\text{Cov}(y,d)=(E[y|d=1]-E[y|d=0])p(1-p)$?

Comment: It can be obtained by algebraic manipulation beginning with a definition of covariance. What definition are you using and where are you stuck?

Comment: Could you _cite_ a few places where this result is stated?

Comment: @DilipSarwate [Here](http://www.mattblackwell.org/files/teaching/s12-iv.pdf) for instance.

Comment: This has been asked and answered--but I am unable to find the thread.  One useful insight is that the right hand side is (obviously) the slope of the ordinary least squares regression of $Y$ on $X$.

Comment: @whuber I hope that stats.SE _doesn't_ already have a proof of the ciaimed result because I think it is false, cf. my answer below.

Comment: @whuber I have edited my answer to what I think might be suitable for a _merger_ of the two threads. Please go ahead and merge the threads, and please make any further necessary edits to my answer as might be needed for the merged threads.

Answer (score 12):

This answer (and all the comments from the second comment onwards on the main question) comes from a [question, now-closed as a duplicate of the one above by ophelie,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/342506/6633) from Thevesh Theva who asked for a proof of
$$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = E[Y\mid X=1] - E[Y\mid X=0],
\tag{1}$$ which is a false result. In fact, for $X \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$ for which $E[X]=p$,
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) &= E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]\\
&= \big(E[XY\mid X=1]\cdot p + E[XY\mid X=0]\cdot(1-p)\big) - p\cdot E[Y]\\
&= E[1\cdot Y\mid X=1]\cdot p + \cancel{E[0\cdot Y\mid X=0]}\cdot(1-p) - p\cdot E[Y]\\
&= E[Y\mid X=1]\cdot p - p\cdot \big(E[Y\mid X=1]\cdot p + E[Y\mid X=0]\cdot (1-p)\big)\\
&= E[Y\mid X=1]\cdot p(1-p) - E[Y\mid X=0]\cdot p(1-p)\\
&= \big(E[Y\mid X=1] - E[Y\mid X=0]\big)\cdot p(1-p) \tag{2}
\end{align}
where we have an extra factor of $p(1-p)$ (with maximum value $\frac 14$)
compared to Thevesh Theva's claim $(1)$.  This result also matches the one asked for above by ophelie which is 
proved more succinctly in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/69698/6633) by Skullduggery.

The claim $(1)$ is a misreading of a result about the *ratio* of two covariances:
$$\frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)}{\operatorname{cov}(X,Z)} =
\frac{E[Y\mid X=1] - E[Y\mid X=0]}{E[Z\mid X=1] - E[Z\mid X=0]}$$
in which the $p(1-p)$ common factor in the numerator and denominator has cancelled out, misleading unwary readers into believing that the authors of the paper are claiming that $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = E[Y\mid X=1] - E[Y\mid X=0]$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. That did mislead me, but your solution cleared it all up.

Answer (score 7):

\begin{eqnarray}
Cov(y,d) &=& E(y \cdot d) - E(y) \cdot E(d) \\
&=& p \cdot E(y|d=1)-[p \cdot E(y|d=1) + (1-p) \cdot E(y|d=0)] \cdot p \\
&=& p \cdot (1-p) \cdot [E(y|d=1) - E(y|d=0)] 
\end{eqnarray}