# Cov(X,Y) when X is a binary variable

Tags: covariance

Say we have a random variable $Y$ which is positive, and a binary variable $X$, i.e. takes values 0 and 1 only.

I have seen (in various places) that:

$$Cov(X,Y) = E[Y | X = 1| - E[Y | X = 0|$$

How do you prove this?

I tried attacking it using the definition:

$$Cov(X,Y) = E[XY| - E[X]E[Y]$$

but it led nowhere.

Comment: @Dilip I agree, but we have fielded a question in which a correct formula is given, as I intimated in the second part of my comment: comparing the OLS formula for the slope to the one given immediately shows a correction factor proportional to the variance of $X$ is needed.  BTW, I just found the duplicate with this search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Cov+binary. Do you have any objection to merging these threads?  It might require a minor change to your answer, because the duplicate quotes the correct formula.